# Browse efficiently through multiple rasters using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, virtual-raster

Is there a way to browse through multiple rasters on QGIS efficiently ? I don't know how to do aside from ticking and unticking the boxes for each of them (see picture) and that really gets old quickly. I tried the raster timeseries manager plugin but it can be tideous to create virtual rasters when the images do not have the same amount of bands.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Place your rasters in the group.
2. Switch the group as `Mutually Exclusive Group` in the context menu.
3. Use <kbd>Space</kbd> to turn visibility on and off.

If your rasters are in the nested groups it may be usefull to solve this [issue](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/38259) (see code in the comments).

Screencast (click to enlarge):

[image]